# Window.hpp file is not found by the Graphics.hpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, sfml, header-files

My Graphics.hpp file cant seem to find the Window.hpp file. Ive tried moving it, using a more specific path, but I still keep getting the error `'SFML/Window.hpp' file not found` even though the file is clearly there in that file path. I am using SFML 2.5.1_2

Entire Graphics.hpp file:

```
#ifndef SFML_GRAPHICS_HPP
#define SFML_GRAPHICS_HPP

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Headers
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <SFML/Window.hpp>  <---------- The error is right here
#include <SFML/Graphics/BlendMode.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/CircleShape.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Color.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/ConvexShape.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Font.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Glyph.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/PrimitiveType.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Rect.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RectangleShape.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderStates.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderTexture.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Shader.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Shape.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Sprite.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Text.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Transform.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Transformable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Vertex.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/VertexArray.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/VertexBuffer.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/View.hpp>


#endif // SFML_GRAPHICS_HPP

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \defgroup graphics Graphics module
///
/// 2D graphics module: sprites, text, shapes, ...
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Please post the command which you are running and the complete error which you are getting. The information you have posted is not sufficient.

Comment: Im running it in vscode so I don't know the command. The error I am getting is posted in the description at the top.

Comment: It should be in the terminal. If you don't know the command then its far from working as you likely have to make multiple changes to your `tasks.json` and `c_cpp_properties.json` for this to work if you are not using CMake and the cmake-tools extension but in that case you need to write a CMakeLists.txt

Comment: The file is part of SFML, it is not your code. How does your code that you are compiling look like?

Comment: It is the green circle code to test sfml 

`#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}`

Comment: That you are using `#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"` instead of `#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>` seems suspiciously like you didn't set the include path to the SFML folder in the compiler invocation, which is something you always must do when adding a library to your project.

Comment: I copied the folder to the project folder. They are located in that local path

Comment: ***I copied the folder to the project folder*** That procedure won't work well. You could get by the include problem with that but then you are not linking to the sfml libraries. You will need to specify those in your tasks.json as arguments to your compiler.

Comment: Where would I include that in tasks.json?

Comment: It's in the args setting. However you must know how to specify command line arguments for whatever compiler you are using.

Comment: This question at the sfml forums should help: [https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24907.0](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=24907.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that they weren't including the include path for a non-standard location for the g++ compiler. To fix this try compiling with the following, replacing the install path with your install path:

```
g++ -c main.cpp -I<sfml-install-path>/include
```

This should fix the problem. See https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-linux.php for more.